# Should I use in or within in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In the following sentence, which preposition should I use and why?

“I was included within the Employer’s Agent team.”
OR
”I was included in the Employer’s Agent team.”

I would greatly appreciate some reasoning for choosing one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "in" in this sentence. This is because "in" usually implies inclusion, while within is more often used to imply a limit or boundary.